# Select values for specific key from all collections in MongoDB using GoLang

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm new to GoLang and MongoDB technologies. I created several documents in a collection and when it is displayed in a single collection, it shows;
[image: View of MongoDB collection]

I need to select only the _id from all the documents in the collection similarly to `SQL SELECT _id FROM Docs`
I didn't find a method to solve this problem using GoLang. But I tried select all the documents and filter the _id from all

```
collection, err := db.GetDBCollectionUnzip("docs")
    var res model.ResponseResult

    findOptions := options.Find()
    findOptions.SetLimit(2)


    var results []*map[string]interface{}

    cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{{}}, findOptions)
```

Since the document content is large, it seems to be a time consuming approach. I hope a guidance for this matter. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is called projection.

Comment: @D.SM I still have some doubts with GoLang and MongoDB. Can you please recommend some resources to study?

Comment: Start with https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection, get it working in mongo shell, then do the same thing in golang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to find the solution. This may be helpful for anyone who is interested.

```
findOptions := options.Find().SetProjection(bson.M{"_id": 1})
findOptions.SetLimit(2)
cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{{}}, findOptions)
```